# Know Present Absent from working date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

[Here is my table](http://rextester.com/FVCS38765)

I want to get all the users that are present/absent between a given date range.

```
CREATE TABLE [tt](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [EmpCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [WorkDate] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [InTime] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [OutTime] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [TotalTime] [varchar](50) NULL,
)
insert into [tt] values
  ('106','E2E106','Goutam Kumar','2017-02-21','12:54:54 PM','10:06:42 PM','08:55:00')
 ,('106','E2E106','Goutam Kumar','2017-02-20','12:49:21 PM','09:26:27 PM','07:53:00')
 ,('106','E2E106','Goutam Kumar','2017-02-15','12:31:51 PM','09:21:14 PM','08:30:00')
 ,('106','E2E106','Goutam Kumar','2017-02-13','05:46:06 PM','09:32:17 PM','03:46:00')
 ,('106','E2E106','Goutam Kumar','2017-02-14','01:02:28 PM','09:32:50 PM','07:39:00')
 ,('111','E2E111','Mansi Manchanda','2017-02-21','12:42:42 PM','09:09:42 PM','08:07:00')
 ,('111','E2E111','Mansi Manchanda','2017-02-17','12:09:11 PM','09:40:46 PM','06:36:00')
 ,('111','E2E111','Mansi Manchanda','2017-02-16','11:56:21 AM','09:20:08 PM','08:07:00')
 ,('111','E2E111','Mansi Manchanda','2017-02-15','01:07:19 PM','09:57:40 PM','08:30:00')

 CREATE TABLE tUserInfo(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [EmpCode] [varchar](200) NULL,
 )
INSERT into tUserInfo VALUES 
('106','Goutam Kumar','E2E106')      
,('111','Mansi Manchanda','E2E111')
,('112','Arvind Kumar Prajapati','E2E112')
,('116','Rahul Garg','E2E116')
```

I am able to get the Present/Absent status of a user for a given date.
But my question here is that I want to get all the users that are present/absent between a given date range.

I want to data look like this:

```
Id  UserId  Name            EmpCode InTime OutTime  WorkDate    Status
1   106 Goutam Kumar    E2E106                  2017-02-13  Present
2   111 Mansi Manchanda E2E111                  2017-02-14  Absent
3   112 Arvind Kumar    E2E112                  2017-02-14  Absent
4   116 Rahul Garg      E2E116                  2017-02-17  Absent
```

Comment: You should be storing your dates as `date` data types.

Comment: Although this does not address your issue, you should take care about normalization. You have the name of the employee (?) twice in your database, once in the `tUserInfo` table and many times in your `tt` table. If any users name changes you will have to go through all the entries in `tt` and change it. Otherwise - if you do not store it here - you just have to change it once in the `tUserInfo` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rextester: http://rextester.com/LCUT68753

Show all users, and either absent entire time or present at least once using `outer apply()` and a `case` expression:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170201'
declare @thrudate date = '20170214'

select u.*
  , Status=case when x.WorkDate is null then 'Absent' else 'Present' end
from tUserInfo as u
outer apply (
  select top 1 tt.WorkDate 
  from tt
  where tt.UserId = u.UserId
    and tt.WorkDate >= @fromdate
    and tt.WorkDate <= @thrudate
    ) as x
```

returns:

```
+----+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| Id | UserId |          Name          | EmpCode | Status  |
+----+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    106 | Goutam Kumar           | E2E106  | Present |
|  2 |    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | E2E111  | Absent  |
|  3 |    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | E2E112  | Absent  |
|  4 |    116 | Rahul Garg             | E2E116  | Absent  |
+----+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+
```

---

Users absent for entire duration, using `not exists()`:

```
select * 
from tUserInfo as u
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from tt
  where tt.UserId = u.UserId
    and tt.WorkDate >= @fromdate
    and tt.WorkDate <= @thrudate
    )
```

returns:

```
+----+--------+------------------------+---------+
| Id | UserId |          Name          | EmpCode |
+----+--------+------------------------+---------+
|  2 |    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | E2E111  |
|  3 |    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | E2E112  |
|  4 |    116 | Rahul Garg             | E2E116  |
+----+--------+------------------------+---------+
```

---

All users present at least once, using `exists()`:

```
select * 
from tUserInfo as u
where exists (
  select 1 
  from tt
  where tt.UserId = u.UserId
    and tt.WorkDate >= @fromdate
    and tt.WorkDate <= @thrudate
    )
```

returns:

```
+----+--------+--------------+---------+
| Id | UserId |     Name     | EmpCode |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+
|  1 |    106 | Goutam Kumar | E2E106  |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+
```

---

To know who was absent and who was present for each `workdate` during the date range:

```
select 
    u.UserId
  , u.Name
  , d.WorkDate
  , [Status] = case when x.WorkDate is null then 'Absent' else 'Present' end
from (select distinct UserId, Name from tUserInfo) as u
  cross join (
    select distinct 
        WorkDate 
    from tt
    where tt.WorkDate >= @fromdate
      and tt.WorkDate <= @thrudate
      ) as d
outer apply (
  select top 1 tt.WorkDate 
  from tt
  where tt.UserId   = u.UserId
    and tt.WorkDate = d.WorkDate
    ) as x
```

returns:

```
+--------+------------------------+------------+---------+
| UserId |          Name          |  WorkDate  | Status  |
+--------+------------------------+------------+---------+
|    106 | Goutam Kumar           | 2017-02-13 | Present |
|    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | 2017-02-13 | Absent  |
|    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | 2017-02-13 | Absent  |
|    116 | Rahul Garg             | 2017-02-13 | Absent  |
|    106 | Goutam Kumar           | 2017-02-14 | Present |
|    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | 2017-02-14 | Absent  |
|    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | 2017-02-14 | Absent  |
|    116 | Rahul Garg             | 2017-02-14 | Absent  |
+--------+------------------------+------------+---------+
```

Note: This only checks `workdate`s that exist in table `tt`.

---

If you need to also check for dates that do not exist in `tt` within your given date range, you can use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to generate the dates for your date range:

```
set @fromdate = '20170212'
set @thrudate = '20170214'

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day
      , row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto      /* 100 days */
      --cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      --cross join n as [tenK]    /* 27.3 years */
   order by [Date]
)
select 
    u.UserId
  , u.Name
  , WorkDate = convert(varchar(10),d.Date,120)
  , [Status] = case when x.WorkDate is null then 'Absent' else 'Present' end
from (select distinct UserId, Name from tUserInfo) as u
  cross join dates as d
outer apply (
  select top 1 tt.WorkDate 
  from tt
  where tt.UserId   = u.UserId
    and tt.WorkDate = d.Date
    ) as x
```

returns:

```
+--------+------------------------+------------+---------+
| UserId |          Name          |  WorkDate  | Status  |
+--------+------------------------+------------+---------+
|    106 | Goutam Kumar           | 2017-02-12 | Absent  |
|    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | 2017-02-12 | Absent  |
|    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | 2017-02-12 | Absent  |
|    116 | Rahul Garg             | 2017-02-12 | Absent  |
|    106 | Goutam Kumar           | 2017-02-13 | Present |
|    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | 2017-02-13 | Absent  |
|    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | 2017-02-13 | Absent  |
|    116 | Rahul Garg             | 2017-02-13 | Absent  |
|    106 | Goutam Kumar           | 2017-02-14 | Present |
|    111 | Mansi Manchanda        | 2017-02-14 | Absent  |
|    112 | Arvind Kumar Prajapati | 2017-02-14 | Absent  |
|    116 | Rahul Garg             | 2017-02-14 | Absent  |
+--------+------------------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: I am afraid columns `[InTime]` , `[OutTime]` are also in game, since usually you want to check whether Employee was there one particular day, i.e. from 9-5. Since you are comparing only dates, you cannot check whether Employee Goutam Kumar was in the office at 21st February from 9 AM to 10 AM.

Comment: @cybersin question states `date` range. "that are present/absent between a given date range."

Comment: @SqlZim there is no work date in the result column how i know in which date employee is absent/Present. thanks.

Comment: @SqlZim but I want to result like this :


   Id UserId Name EmpCode WorkDate Status
1 1 106 Goutam Kumar E2E106 2017-02-13 Present
2 2 111 Mansi Manchanda E2E111 2017-02-14      Absent
3 3 112 Arvind Kumar           E2E112 2017-02-14      Absent
4 4 116 Rahul Garg          E2E116  2017-02-16     Absent

Comment: @GoutamSingh Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using pivot concept and fetching all the dates and then placing the users respectively

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.WorkDate) 
            FROM tt c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Id,UserId,EmpCode, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Id
                    , UserId
                    , EmpCode
                    ,Name
                    ,WorkDate

                from tt
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Name)
                for WorkDate in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

[image]